# Laravel 5.1 hasManyThrough Pivot table

Tags: laravel-5, many-to-many, pivot-table, has-many-through

I have model many to many relation like. I want to relate **State** and **Category** through pivot table CategoryNews.

Category model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function news() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\News');

    } 
}
```

News model

```
class News extends Model
    {
         public function categories()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
        }
        public function state()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\State');
        }
}
```

and the State model

```
class State extends Model
{
    public function news() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\News');

    }  
}
```

I want to select the news related to the state where cat_type=2(from category table)
i tried

```
$slide_news = State::whereHas('news.categories',function($query){ $query->where('categories.cat_type',2);})

                    ->with(array('news'=>function($query){ 
                    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');}
                   ))->where('id',$id)->first();
```

but the cat_type filter is not working. I also tried hasManyThrough but i don't know how to implement it with Pivot Table
Please help

Answer (score 2):

There is a Laravel 5.5 composer package that can perform multi-level relationships (deep)

Package:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Example:

`User` → belongs to many → `Role` → belongs to many → `Permission`

```
class User extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            'App\Permission',
            ['role_user', 'App\Role', 'permission_role'], // Pivot tables/models starting from the Parent, which is the User
        );
    }
}
```

Example if foreign keys need to be defined:

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep/issues/7#issuecomment-431477943

---

To the moderators:
DO NOT DELETE MY ANSWER

It took me two god damn days to solve this issue, and I was so happy i found the solution that i want to let the world know

Notice that my answer was upvoted, yet you deleted it.

The question's title is regarding: hasManyThrough Pivot table for Laravel, and my answer gives just that, a solution to perform hasManyThrough equivalent on Pivot Tables

The question was 3 years old, and let's admit no one wants a solution specific to the question, because we've all got our own.
If I were you, I'd prefer a generic answer.